# form not submit error comes as null entry for parameter in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created controller for add comment on web page. below is my comment controller

```
public ActionResult AddComment(int id=0)
{
    int spid = id;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddComment(comment cmt,int spid)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        cmt.SPID = spid;
        db.comments.Add(cmt);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Comment");
    }
    return View(cmt);
}
```

this is AddComment View

```
@model WEB1.Models.comment
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Comment"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>comment</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cmd_content)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cmd_content)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cmd_content)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.t_email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.t_email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.t_email)
        </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SPID)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

below is comment model

```
[Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CMT_ID { get; set; }

    private DateTime _date = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime cmd_ad
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set { _date = value; }
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please add Comment before submit")]
    public string cmd_content { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$",
    ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Correct Email Address")]
    public string t_email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SPID { get; set; }
```

I have got error message

> 'The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'spid' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AddComment(WEB1.Models.comment, Int32)' in 'WEB1.Controllers.CommentController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters'.

I have debugged my code it doesn't hit on post Action method. How do I fix this problem.

Comment: I have modified my Question

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks a lot.It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not pass a model to the view so the value of property `SPID` is `null` in the view (your `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SPID)` is generating `<input type="hidden" name="SPID" .... value="" />`) so a `null` value is posted when you submit the form.

Change your GET method to initialize the model, set its property, and then return that model to the view

```
public ActionResult AddComment(int id = 0)
{
    var model = new comment(){ SPID = id };
    return View(model );
}
```

and you can also remove the `int spid` parameter in your POST method since the value is already bound to the `SPID` property of `cmt`

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddComment(comment cmt)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.comments.Add(cmt);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Comment");
    }
    return View(cmt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the error message, it's clearly saying what's wrong. Your post method models are not binded properly. parameter `spid` is null and so it's failing while validating model binding, particularly in the line `if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {`

Your error message

> a null entry for parameter 'spid' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'
>   for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AddComment(WEB1.Models.comment